# Match on two subqueries with count

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to check if the count from two tables are the same

I have one query:

```
SELECT Count(1) AS Items,
       [Basket Id],
       [Customer Id]
FROM   Order_Lookup
GROUP  BY [Basket Id],
          [Customer Id]
```

Which returns:

```
3   2   135674
5   4   115576
3   5   115576
2   3   118342
4   6   182368
```

And I also have:

```
SELECT Count(1) AS Items,
                 a.[Basket Id],
                 a.[Customer Id]
          FROM   C1059204.Order_Lookup a
          WHERE  a.[Product Id] NOT IN (SELECT [Product Id]
                                        FROM   Orders
                                        WHERE  [Customer_Id] = a.[Customer Id]
                                               AND OrderDate = Dateadd(DAY, Datediff(DAY, 0, Getutcdate()), -2)
                                               AND OrderStatus IN ('POSTED' ))
          GROUP  BY a.[Basket Id],
                    a.[Customer Id]
```

Which returns:

```
3   2   135674
3   4   115576
3   5   115576
2   3   118342
4   6   182368
```

As you can see 115576 Basket Id 4 has a lower number.

I need to have a query like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE (COUNT OF FIRST SUBQUERY) = (COUNT OF SECOND SUBQUERY)
```

How can I do this, I have been trying for a long time now and can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you nested select each query and `INNER JOIN` the results

Comment: Do you want your result to be grouped with counts like your two subqueries, or do you just want to have all records from `Order_Lookup` that fulfil the condition of having the same counts for both subqueries?

Comment: I want to have my results from Order_Lookup, I don't care about the counts as long as they're checking for a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap both subqueries and join on the alias names.

```
select *
from (
    SELECT Count(1) AS Items,
           [Basket Id],
           [Customer Id]
    FROM   Order_Lookup
    GROUP  BY [Basket Id],
              [Customer Id]
) as query1
join (
    SELECT Count(1) AS Items,
                     a.[Basket Id],
                     a.[Customer Id]
              FROM   C1059204.Order_Lookup a
              WHERE  a.[Product Id] NOT IN (SELECT [Product Id]
                                            FROM   Orders
                                            WHERE  [Customer_Id] = a.[Customer Id]
                                                   AND OrderDate = Dateadd(DAY, Datediff(DAY, 0, Getutcdate()), -2)
                                                   AND OrderStatus IN ('POSTED' ))
              GROUP  BY a.[Basket Id],
                        a.[Customer Id] 
) as query2 on query1.Items = query2.Items
```

Comment: You will have to add `[Basket Id]` and `[Customer Id]` to your join criteria, and maybe project only `query1.*`

Comment: @LukasEder - I started the ask the same question, but the question specifically states 'count1 = count2' without any other criteria

Comment: True, there are some doubts. Also, it's not so clear whether the actual result should be grouped or not...

Comment: @LukasEder - Yeah, a couple no doubt.  I was merely showing the OP how to take two subqueries and join them on some related criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
SELECT count(*),
       subquery.[Basket Id],
       subquery.[Customer Id] 
FROM (
  -- Put your subselect in a case expression returning 1 or 0 to indicate
  -- whether it would evaluate to true or false for any given record
  SELECT CASE WHEN a.[Product Id] IN (
                SELECT [Product Id]
                  FROM Orders
                 WHERE [Customer_Id] = a.[Customer Id]
                   AND OrderDate = Dateadd(DAY, Datediff(DAY, 0, Getutcdate()), -2)
                   AND OrderStatus IN ('POSTED' ))
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END [isPosted],
       a.[Basket Id],
       a.[Customer Id]
   FROM   C1059204.Order_Lookup a
 ) subquery
 GROUP  BY subquery.[Basket Id],
           subquery.[Customer Id] 
 -- Those groups that contain at least one record which would figure in your 
 -- "second subquery" should be omitted altogether
 HAVING SUM([isPosted]) = 0
```